# Recursively go through directories and extract files one directory up CLI

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

Currently, I am using this

```
unrar e -r *.rar
```

To extract files, however this puts everything in my root unraring folder.  Current structure

```
/HomeFolder
    /Nextlevel
        /RarFolder
            rarfile.rar
```

I want the output to be

```
/HomeFolder
    /Nextlevel
        raroutput.ext
```

How would I do change my command to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following approach:

```
find /HomeFolder -type d -name 'RarFolder' -printf '%h\n' | xargs -I{} sh -c 'cd {}; unrar e -r *.rar'
```

It searches for all nested 'RarFolder' subdirectories in '/HomeFolder', running your *unrar* command from within subdir containing 'RarFolder' (i.e. '/HomeFolder/Nextlevel' in your example).

---

To extract files to parent directory of one, containing '*.rar' files, command can be adjusted as:

```
find /HomeFolder -type f -name '*.rar' -printf '%h\n' | xargs -I{} sh -c 'cd {}/..; unrar e -r *.rar'
```

Comment: Rarfolder is just an example, NextLevel and Rarfolder have unknown names.  I just need all rars extracted 1 directory above where the rar file is

Comment: @BrianJ I've adjusted my answer for this case